# PHP: Pass on form data to a third file without changing it in the second file

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to pass on form1 data from file1.php to file3.php, then go to file2.php have a new form2 and then pass on the data from form2 to file3.php. However, so far I only have the data from form2 in file3 but I don't know how to pass on or get the data from form1 (file1.php).

file1.php with my form1 data

```
<form method="post" name="cartForm" action="file2.php?act=form">
    <div class="card-group">
        <div class="card">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="./images/10-11017B.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Basic Black Polo</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Word on the street is that 'black is the new black.'</p>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <label class="card-text">Amount</label>
                <input type="number" step="1" value="1" class="form-control amount-input" name="amountProd1">
                <label class="card-text">Price</label>
                <input type="number" step="1" value="30" class="form-control amount-input" name="priceProd1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="checkout-button">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Checkout" />
    </div>
</form>
```

file2.php with form2 data (Here I have the data from form 1 - amountProd1)

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST['amountProd1']); //  1 is printed here
?>
<!-- end php code -->
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <form method="post" name="addressForm" action="file3.php?act=form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="checkout-button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Continue" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

file3.php where I have the form2 data from file2.php but I no longer have the data from form 1 from file1.php:

```
<?php

    print_r($_POST['amountProd1']); // nothing is printed here
?>
<!-- end php code -->
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <form method="post" name="paymentForm" action="file4.php?act=form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="payment">Payment</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="payment" id="payment">
            </div>
            <div class="checkout-button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Continue" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me how to pass on the form1 data in file2 so I can access them in file3?

Comment: use `SESSIONS` to pass

Comment: I agree with @BanujanBalendrakumar - If you are going from file to file, you will need to save the data to a $_SESSION variable. In the file2, you can recall all of the information and unset the session variable. For example, in file2, you can have $_SESSION['amountProd1'] = $_POST['amountProd1'], then do your thing with file3, then come back to file2. Just don't overwrite the session variables. NOTE: If you end up having an array that you need to save to the session variable, you can serialize and unserialize them.

Comment: @Apolymoxic but does that mean I have to set the session variable newly in file2 even though I don't change them in order to access them in file3?

Comment: @threxx No. The session variables will stay in tact until either the session or the session variable is destroyed. Just remember to set `session_start();` on each page - this should be the first line (after `<?php`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the details captured in the first form in the `SESSIONS` variable or use hidden inputs to retain the data on the second page, then forward it to the third page.

Then remember that all your page should have a `session_start();` at the top of the page.

```
<?php 
session_start();
```

It is this call that gives each script access to the SESSION and the contents saved within it

Comment: do I have to add the variable in the second file again to the session? Because it seems like if i set them on page1 then go to page2 then go to page3, page3 doesnt have them

Comment: You have to remember that ALL your pages shoudl have a `session_start()` at the top of the page for session to work properly

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP $_SESSION to keep variables between forms

Exemple in file2.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['amountProd1'] = $_POST['amountProd1'];
```

in file3.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
print_r($_SESSION['amountProd1']);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use hidden inputs

append form in data2 with:

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['amountProd1']; ?>">
```

and do same with data3 and finally all data will be sent to your file4.php

Answer (score 0):

**file2.php**

```
    <div class="container">
    <div>
        <form method="post" name="addressForm" action="file3.php?act=form">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['amountProd1']; ?>" name="amountProd1">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_POST['priceProd1']; ?>" name="priceProd1">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname" id="firstname">
            </div>
            <div class="checkout-button">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Continue" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```